# Does one need to fast if a pasul Torah is dropped?

Tags: minhag, sefer-torah

There is a [minhag to fast](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/830339/jewish/Why-fast-after-dropping-a-Torah-scroll-or-tefillin.htm) when a Sefer Torah is dropped. Does this apply if the dropped Torah was *pasul* (not "kosher")?

My thinking - a pasul Torah is not a "true" Torah in the sense that it can be used for congregational reading. However, it still maintains its holiness and it needs to be buried if one wants to "dispose" it. But, despite that, perhaps, the minhag applies only to usable Sifrei Torah?

Comment: 1. What kind of a pesul are we talking about? 2. Does the minhag apply to an 85-letter scroll, or only a full one?

Comment: @DonielF You completely lost me. Please explain why these make a difference.

Comment: If it has more than 85 letters, it may still have kedushah depending on the pesul (i.e. are Parsha breaks messed up, or were the Sheimos written improperly?)

Comment: Technically, even a Chumash that has all 5 books is a pasul Sefer Torah, from what I remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Maharsham [Daas Torah](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41144&st=&pgnum=108&hilite=) says that one should fast when a Pasul Sefer Torah falls, and that seems to be the opinion of most Poskim [quoted in Nitei Gavriel](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46547&st=&pgnum=226&hilite=).

Comment: Is this assuming it had once been kosher?

Comment: @DoubleAA - The Daas Torah's sources seem to be talking about when they started off as Kosher Sifrei Torah.